# Spring Boot MVC request mapping overrides static resources

Tags: spring-boot, static-resource

I want to have rest controller in Spring Boot to handle all requests like this: "/{arg}", EXCEPT "/sitemap.xml". How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify your request mapping on the controller level via regex and exclude some resources (e.g. 'excludeResourceA' and 'excludeResourceB') with:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/{arg:(?!sitemap.xml|excludeResourceA|excludeResourceB).*$}")
public class YourRestController {
    // your implementation
}
```

Of course you can also specify the request mapping on the method level with the same regex relative to your controller path matching and you can pass the argument with `@PathVariable("arg") String arg` in your method signature to your method body if you need it.